# after changing the date into strtotime it gives wrong date

Tags: php, datetime, date-format

I have date in `UK format` i.e. 27/05/15
i am changing the date into 27-05-2015 format and than saving in database in `strtotime('27-05-2015')` and than changing it to my date format but it returns today's date. following is my code.

```
  $line['date'] = '27/05/15';
  $line['date'] = substr_replace($line['date'], '20', -2, 0);
  $line['date'] = str_replace('/', '-', $line['date']);
  print_r(strtotime($line['date'])); // gives than on changing the date to date format 
  print_r(date('d/m/y'),strtotime($line['date']));
```

i am getting  31-10-15 (i.e today's date)

Please let me how to resolve this issue

Comment: where did you come up with `$line['Order-date']` from?  you are not using the same variable all the way...

Comment: When I run the code, once I change `$line['Order-date']` to `$line['date']` it words as expected

Answer (score 0):

you are messing up with date(). it should be

```
print_r(date('d/m/y', strtotime($line['date'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but maybe you need to change your date format before insert it to database.

Try change this line

```
$line['date'] = str_replace('/', '-', $line['date']);
```

to this

```
list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $line['date']);
$line['date'] = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

So, your date will look like  `2015-05-27` before insert to database